# Fast way to find the page before and after the one I want

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I'm a beginner in mysql and I wanted to know if there is a faster way to do the following:

I have a table like this:

```
------------------------------
| Pages |      Creation      |
------------------------------
| bar   | 2012-10-10 10:11:10|
| blah  | 0000-00-00 00:00:00|
| foo   | 2012-10-10 10:10:10|
------------------------------
```

There is no primary key.

I want to know the page before and the page after a specific page (Ordered by date of creation).

Currently I do:

Sql: `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY creation`

Php:

```
foreach($r as $c=>$t)
{
    if($t['pages']==$thepageiwant)
    {
        $before=$c-1;
        $after=$c+1;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use a primary key so that you can absolutely identify the current page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previous page:

```
SELECT table.Pages
FROM table, (SELECT Creation FROM table WHERE Pages = "'.$page.'") AS t2
WHERE table.Creation < t2.Creation
ORDER BY  table.Creation DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Next page:

```
SELECT table.Pages
FROM table, (SELECT Creation FROM table WHERE Pages = "'.$page.'") AS t2
WHERE table.Creation > t2.Creation
ORDER BY  table.Creation ASC
LIMIT 1
```